# View all registered DLLs on Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, dll

I would like to see if DLL registration was successful on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  Is there any way to view a list of all registered DLLs??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register a dll and extract its class ID and other information, it stores it in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID} in the registry. Probably the easiest thing to do is open up that registry hive, right click and search for the complete file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use Powershell applet: gdwi win32_services

Comment: Could you add some more detail - perhaps a usage example?